# Spring RMI-IIOP(CORBA) with spring-aop

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-remoting, iiop

I am trying to implement rmi-iiop using spring. I searched a lot but didn't find any latest example of it. So I started with Exposing Corba Services section in [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=S2ZZepXWmmMC&pg=PA540&lpg=PA540&dq=spring+corba+remoting&source=bl&ots=XpTlcCw4xS&sig=e3aygIAaVnJqMfqbCvbShQHwXTs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwA2oVChMImLbzspPuxwIVCm2OCh2CKwbD#v=onepage&q=spring%20corba%20remoting&f=false). Even though it is written based on older spring version, it seems to work.

These are my configurations

**Server**

```
public interface IRemote extends Remote{
    String getMsg() throws RemoteException;
} 
public class RemoteImpl implements IRemote {
    @Override
    public String getMsg() throws RemoteException {
            return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Beans

```
<bean id="helloWorldService"
            class="com.sample.remote.RemoteImpl" />

<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiServiceExporter">
            <property name="jndiName" value="HelloWorld"/>
            <property name="serviceInterface"
                    value="com.sample.remote.IRemote" />
            <property name="service" ref="helloWorldService"/>
            <property name="jndiEnvironment">
                    <props>
                            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">
                                    com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory
                            </prop>
                            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">iiop://localhost:1050</prop>
                    </props>
            </property>
</bean>
```

**Client**

```
<bean id="helloWorldService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName">
                    <value>HelloWorld</value>
            </property>

            <property name="serviceInterface">
                    <value>com.sample.remote.IRemote</value>
            </property>
            <property name="jndiEnvironment">
                    <props>
                            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">
                                    com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory
                            </prop>
                            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">iiop://localhost:1050</prop>
                    </props>
            </property>
</bean>
```

Client class

```
public class Client {
    @Autowired
    IRemote remote;

    public void clientMethod() {
            try {
                    System.out.println(remote.getMsg());
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

This works fine as such.

But the problem is when using spring aop. As aop creates a proxy bean, the stub/tie lookup fails in the server with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiServiceExporter#0' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Code-base/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/sample-web/WEB-INF/lib/tech-ri-remote-1.0.0-M1.jar!/config/test_SpringContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.rmi.StubNotFoundException: Stub class not found: $Proxy203_Stub; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $Proxy203_Stub
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.rmi.StubNotFoundException: Stub class not found: $Proxy203_Stub; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $Proxy203_Stub
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.createStub(Util.java:292)
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.createProxy(Util.java:140)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:196)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:310)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:237)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.exportObject(PortableRemoteObject.java:119)
        at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.exportObject(PortableRemoteObject.java:103)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiServiceExporter.prepare(JndiRmiServiceExporter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiServiceExporter.afterPropertiesSet(JndiRmiServiceExporter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $Proxy203_Stub
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.createStub(Util.java:286)
        ... 32 more
```

Even though the exception says $Proxy203_Stub not found, on debugging I found that the actual exception occurs when Tie lookup fails.

So as another option mentioned in the JndiRmiServiceExporter javadoc, I tried without the java.rmi.Remote interface and RemoteException. But then bean creation fails with RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub not found.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiServiceExporter#0' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Code-base/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/sample-web/WEB-INF/lib/tech-ri-remote-1.0.0-M1.jar!/config/test_SpringContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.rmi.StubNotFoundException: Stub class not found: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.rmi.StubNotFoundException: Stub class not found: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.createStub(Util.java:292)
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.createProxy(Util.java:140)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:196)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:310)
        at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:237)
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.exportObject(PortableRemoteObject.java:119)
        at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.exportObject(PortableRemoteObject.java:103)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiServiceExporter.prepare(JndiRmiServiceExporter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiServiceExporter.afterPropertiesSet(JndiRmiServiceExporter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at sun.rmi.server.Util.createStub(Util.java:286)
        ... 32 more
```

Here also, the actual exception occurs on failure of Tie lookup.

I saw that RmiInvocationWrapper stub and tie are [not part of spring-context.jar in the latest releases](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/upgrade/spring3/html/ch04s02.html) and are no longer needed for rmi. But I didn't see anything as such related to rmi-iiop. So assuming the stub and tie are needed, I created _RmiInvocationWrapper_Tie.class and _RmiInvocationHandler_Stub.class and added them to the jar. Then the server started working.

But on starting the client, it fails with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldService' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Code-base/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/sample-web/WEB-INF/lib/tech-ri-1.0.0-M1.jar!/config/techri_SpringContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Could not narrow RMI stub to service interface [com.sample.remote.IRemote]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Could not narrow RMI stub to service interface [com.sample.remote.IRemote]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(JndiRmiClientInterceptor.java:237)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiClientInterceptor.prepare(JndiRmiClientInterceptor.java:199)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiClientInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(JndiRmiClientInterceptor.java:187)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean.java:79)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:245)
        at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:153)
        at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(JndiRmiClientInterceptor.java:233)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Object is not of remote type com.sample.remote.IRemote
        at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:237)
        ... 29 more
```

So I am completely stuck now and don't know how to proceed.
Please advise. Also it would be better if someone can provide any latest example configurations based on this.